# Duda con DrawerLayout y NavigationView al intentar abrirlo desde un ImageView

Tags: android, android-fragment, android-drawerlayout

En el `ActivityMain` de mi aplicación, tengo creado un `DrawerLayout` y un `NavigationView` el cual funciona perfectamente y dentro del menú que se despliega tengo puesto varios enlaces a `fragment` que van cambiando según se hace clic en ellos.

Hasta aquí todo bien.

El problema lo tengo dentro de un `fragment`.
En este `fragment` sólo muestro una imagen que ocupa toda la pantalla y mi intención es que cuando se pulse la imagen se muestre el `DrawerLayout` con el menú lateral.

He probado a crear un objeto de la clase `MainActivity` para llamar al `drawerLayout` pero esto provoca un error y creo que así no es la solución.

En este instante el código de mi `fragment` es:

```
   public class FragmentInicio extends Fragment {

        public FragmentInicio() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Inflate the layout for this fragment
            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_inicio, container, false);
            ImageView logo = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageEccaInicio);
            logo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view){
                    Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Se ha tocado la imagen", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    //drawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                }
            });
            return v;
        }

    }
```

También intenté hacer esto desde el `MainActivity` pero también producía un error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final resultó más fácil de lo que pensé.

1º En el `MainActivity` creé un método para que se abriera el `DrawerLayout`

```
public void openDrawer(){
        drawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
}
```

2º En el `Fragment` donde tengo la imagen cuando se produce el evento `onClick`
he llamado al método del `MainActivity`

```
ImageView logo = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageEccaInicio);
        logo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view){
                Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Se ha tocado la imagen", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                ((MainActivity)getActivity()).openDrawer();
            }
        });
```

Al parecer una mejor manera es crear un Listener, pero no lo conseguí. 
Esta es la solución que me funcionó a mi.

Espero que os sirva, un saludo y gracias a Nicol Israel Olvera Acosta

Answer (score 1):

Un listener amigo

```
public interface DrawerListener {
    void openDrawer();
}
```

Lo implementas en tu MainActivity y se lo pasas como argumento al fragment

```
Fragment frag = new TuFragment();
frag.setDrawerListener(MainActivity.this);
```

y en el fragment

```
mDrawerListener.openDrawer();
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta, pero intenté hacerlo y no me funcionó.
Aunque si encontré cómo hacerlo y lo pongo más a bajo. Para que otras personas lo puedan saber.
Un saludo